# How do I solve this non-separable DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y-2xy}{x^{2}-x+y}$$

It's not (immediately) separable, homogeneous, and I can't factor...

Comment: Do you know about exact equations? That's the most common other situation that you encounter among first order equations in a class on elementary differential equations.

Comment: @Ian yes I do. I actually studied them much earlier in my class so I must just be rusty right now! (This problem was part of a bigger problem to do with phase planes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite this as \begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-2xy}{x^2-x+y}&\iff(x^2-x+y)dy=(y-2xy)dx\\[0.2cm]&\iff\left(x^2y-xy+\frac{y^2}2\right)'dy+\left(x^2y-xy+\frac{y^2}{2}\right)'dx=0\end{align} where the first derivative is with respect to $y$ and the second with respect to $x$. Hence, the function $$F(x,y)=x^2y-xy+\frac{y^2}{2}$$ is an exact potential for the ODE, since $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-2xy}{x^2-x+y}\iff \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}dy=0$$ Now, depending on your initial value, the solutions are given by all $y$ that satisfy $F(x,y)=c$, i.e. all $y$ such that $$\frac{1}{2}y^2+(x^2-x)y-c=0\implies y_{1,2}(x)=-x(x-1)\pm\sqrt{(x^2-x)^2+4c}$$